# Simple frequency distribution chart or formula (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, distribution, frequency

Have used this forum to help solve a few spreadsheet issues in the past (so many thank for all the donated time and expertise).

Hoping the community can help with something that thought initially to be quite simple but I can't find the answer or solution anywhere.

I have a list of values and I want to create a frequency distribution list from this. I don't want to collect the data into ranges (i.e. histogram style) but I do need to know exactly how many instances there are of each value. Values in spreadsheet example below.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10gkP4DLA_k8yrbVdNEFmrDwKrg-B_t6BUkAmPNE2CpQ/edit#gid=0

I don't need the data presented in a graph but if a graph is the easiest way to collate this then that's fine as I will need to routinely do this calculation.

Many thanks.
db

Answer (score 1):

A 'group by' query should do this:

```
=query(B3:B,"select B,count(B) where B is not null group by B label B 'Value'")
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Tom - that is exactly what I was trying to achieve :)